# Related table displaying nothing instead of name after attempting to look up name from related table

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

EDIT:
Changed a couple of classes compared to what they are below to match the Microsoft guide on Relationships.

Devices.cs

```
public partial class Devices
{
    public int DeviceType { get; set; }
...
    public DeviceTypes DeviceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

DeviceTypes.cs

```
public partial class DeviceTypes
{
    public int DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Devices Devices { get; set; }
}
```

I then changed my view to start reading off of DeviceTypes.Name.

Index.cshtml

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeviceTypes.Name)
```

dbContext.cs

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Devices>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceId);

            ...

            entity.Property(e => e.DeviceType).HasComment("ID of the type of devices. Primary key in DeviceTypes table.");

            ...

            entity
            .HasOne(p => p.DeviceTypes)
            .WithOne(p => p.Devices);
        });

....

        modelBuilder.Entity<DeviceTypes>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.DeviceType);

            entity.HasComment("The types of devices.");

            entity.Property(e => e.DeviceType)
                .HasComment("Id of the device.")
                .ValueGeneratedNever();

            entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .HasComment("Name of the device.");
            entity
                .HasOne(b => b.Devices)
                .WithOne(i => i.DeviceTypes)
                .HasForeignKey("DeviceType");
        });
```

I also added to the model builder, but got stuck again not understanding. I've spent a few more hours trying but I can't figure it out. The current error I get is:

**InvalidOperationException: You are configuring a relationship between 'DeviceTypes' and 'Devices' but have specified a foreign key on 'DeviceType'. The foreign key must be defined on a type that is part of the relationship.**

---

This is a question about using related tables in my CRUD editors in .NET Core 3.1. I want to use the Name instead of the ID as a display on the index/details/delete pages. And on the create/edit pages I want to use a dropdown to select the value from a list.

There are quite a few examples I have found, but nothing I have tried yet has worked. I had too many different ideas mixed in my code before so I tossed all changes and I am trying again, but got stuck.

I am starting simple with adding my model again and trying to simply get it to display in my paginated list. Currently, the paged list displays no value at all rather than a name or ID. Obviously I am trying to get the Name to display. Then I will move toward something more complicated like getting this value in a dropdown on the create page.

I know I am not figuring out the part about linking the data from the database back into my view model, but I have spent so many hours on this today and haven't quite found the missing piece. I have had so many variations on this that didn't work and this was trying to start by keeping it as simple as I could and then ask you all for advice.

Here is the code I am working with:

Devices.cs - DeviceType is really the ID

```
public partial class Devices
{
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }
    public int DeviceType { get; set; }
...
    [NotMapped]
    public DeviceTypes DeviceTypes { get; set; }
}
```

DeviceTypes.cs - This is what I want to look up by DeviceType (int) and use the name in the editors

```
public partial class DeviceTypes
{
    public int DeviceType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DevicesViewModel.cs

```
public class DevicesViewModel
{
    public Devices Devices { get; set; }
    public PaginatedList<Devices> DevicesPagedList { get; set; }

}
```

DevicesController.cs - This is in the Index method where I get the data and then later what I am passing into my view

```
var devices = from dev in _context.Devices
                      select dev;
...
return base.View(new DevicesViewModel { DevicesPagedList = await PaginatedList<Devices>.CreateAsync(devices.AsNoTracking(), currentPage, resultsPerPage ?? 10), ResultsPerPageList = SelectListItemHelper.ResultsPerPageList().Where(l => l.Text != (resultsPerPage ?? 10).ToString()) });
}
```

Finally, here is where I am trying to display the value in Index.cshtml

```
@model DevicesViewModel

...
        @foreach (var item in Model.DevicesPagedList)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DeviceTypes.Name)
                </td>
...
```

Comment: Remove `[NotMapped]` attribute from `Devices.DeviceTypes` property, rename it to `DeviceType` (to match the FK convention - see [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key)) and use `Include` method to load it - see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Comment: Ivan, thank you. I think I made progress. But, maybe I am going backwards again. I sped a few more hours on this. I updated my answer with my changes since your post. Any chance you know what I am missing? I am trying to set up the FK relationship. Also, I haven't gotten to the next step, but I do not know where to put the .include?

Comment: BTW I might have figured out the include part, but, again, maybe I am wrong. 

return base.View(new DevicesViewModel { DevicesPagedList = await PaginatedList<Devices>.CreateAsync(devices.AsNoTracking().Include(Devices => Devices.DeviceTypes), currentPage, resultsPerPage ?? 10), ResultsPerPageList = SelectListItemHelper.ResultsPerPageList().Where(l => l.Text != (resultsPerPage ?? 10).ToString()) });

Comment: NEVERMIND! This just made things worse again. I am going backwards again all day Ahhhh! I am so confused.

Comment: Tried setting up the relationship with Data Annotations and also with the Fluent API. Another error I commonly get depending on which way I have things messed up is : InvalidOperationException: The relationship from 'DeviceTypes.Devices' to 'Devices' with foreign key properties {'DeviceType' : int} cannot target the primary key {'DeviceId' : string} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.

Comment: OMG I figured it out finally. I set the relationship in the Devices.cs class with a Data Annotation of         [ForeignKey(nameof(DeviceType))] on public DeviceTypes DeviceTypes { get; set; }